# Jekyll/Liquid: How do I pass post front matter to a custom tag?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm following [this demonstration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/tags/) of building custom liquid tags.

I want to create a tag that takes the image of a given post and returns an image tag with the path to its equivalent thumbnail.

Say the frontmatter for a post looks like this:

```
---
title: Build a plugin
layout: post
image: plugin.jpg
---
```

My tag would look like this:

```
{% thumb_for post.image %}
```

The desired output would be:

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/thumbs/plugin.jpg">
```

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
module Jekyll
  class RenderThumbTag < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, image, tokens)
      super
      @image = image
    end

    def render(context)
      "<img src='#{context["site"]["url"]}/images/thumbs/#{@image}'>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('thumb_for', Jekyll::RenderThumbTag)
```

However, the rendered tag ends up as `http://example.com/images/thumbs/post.image`. Obviously I want `post.image` to evaluate to the file name. What steps do I need to take? (Or have I got Liquid all wrong?)

### Edit

I realise that my main problem is that I don't know how to reference the current iteration in this `posts` loop:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li class="post">
    {% thumb_for %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

`thumb_for` should return the thumbnail tag for each `post` in `posts`.

## Edit 2

Of course, I should define `thumb` on individual posts. I think I need to understand how to define custom variables for specific page types.

Comment: I am unclear how the front matter is supposed to combine with the argument to the tag to produce the output. You said "Obviously I want post.image to evaluate to the file name." but that is not obvious (to me). Can you be more explicit? Seems like the tag argument is to be ignored, is that right?

Comment: In other words, you just want to use the front matter variable to construct the output, is that right?

Comment: BTW, `#{context["site"]["url"]}` returns the protocol, domain and perhaps port number, all of which are unnecessary. You could omit all of that and just return an absolute path like `/images/thumbs/plugin.jpg`. Simpler is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the front matter variable, and any argument to the custom tag is to be ignored, this should do the job:

```rb
module Jekyll
  class RenderThumbTag < Liquid::Tag
    def render(context)
      page = context.registers[:page]
      "<img src='/images/thumbs/#{page.image}'>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('thumb_for', Jekyll::RenderThumbTag)
```

You would invoke the tag like this:

```
{% thumb_for %}
```

BTW, I provide [sample templates for Jekyll plugins](https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/12/30/jekyll-plugin-template-collection.html) on my blog.